# Why does my CMYK file have crazy neon colors?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, print-design, cmyk, jpg

I am new to Illustrator but made a very cool file with photos & text to print as 11x14 poster.  A JPEG file is needed to bring to the printer (using Costco which usually works fine).  But when I get to the printing kiosk & open the file, it's appearance looks posterized with crazy neon colors. It's not even close to the colors of the original file. The color is set at CMYK & I'm choosing highest quality (10) in the save options.  The .jpeg file looks fine when opened on my iPhone or another computer.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: .. save as RGB not CMYK. 99.9% of the people going to costco for self-printing are using RGB files... that's what it's designed to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly they are using an aplication that does not read right a cmyk file (or you did not embed it).

The visualization is not a problem, the problem **could** be that that program does not recognize embeded profiles.

Anyway, make a sample print and make decisions based on that.

Or use an RGB file, but still, you need to make a test. If the project is important, print a small file to see the colors (I would not trust a kiosk monitor at all), and make adjustments on you computer.

Comment: If it was embedded would it read correctly?   if so, can you explain how to do that?

Comment: If you embeded it it is all you can do from your part. Simply, the aplication of the kiosk is too primitive. But, just make a simple test (print a small pice), to compare the colors. You need to do that anyway in rgb or cmyk.

Comment: i'm not sure if I embeded it or not.  How can I tell?

Comment: @Donna Rafael is probably right, it makes perfect sense. The same kind of thing happens when uploading files to online printers; the preview is often neon and horrible but the finished printed colors are alright. It will do this embedded profile or not I think; check their requirements and make a small run to be sure!